# Processing upserts on a large number of partitions is not fast enough

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

**The Problem**

We have a Delta Lake setup on top of ADLS Gen2 with the following tables:

- `bronze.DeviceData`: partitioned by arrival date (`Partition_Date`)
- `silver.DeviceData`: partitioned by event date and hour (`Partition_Date` and `Partition_Hour`)

We ingest large amounts of data (>600M records per day) from an event hub into `bronze.DeviceData` (append-only). We then process the new files in a streaming fashion and upsert them into `silver.DeviceData` with the delta MERGE command (see below).

The data arriving in the bronze table can contain data from *any* partition in silver (e.g. a device may send historic data that it cached locally). However, >90% of the data arriving at any day is from partitions `Partition_Date IN (CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAYS, CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAYS)`. Therefore, to upsert the data, we have the following two spark jobs:

- "Fast": processes the data from the three date partitions above. The latency is important here, so we prioritize this data
- "Slow": processes the rest (anything *but* these three date partitions). The latency doesn't matter so much, but it should be within a "reasonable" amount of time (not more than a week I'd say)

Now we come to the problem: although the amount of data is magnitudes less in the "slow" job, it runs for days just to process a single day of slow bronze data, with a big cluster. The reason is simple: it has to read and update many silver partitions (> 1000 date partitions at times), and since the updates are small but the date partitions can be gigabytes, these merge commands are inefficient.

Furthermore, as time goes on, this slow job will become slower and slower, since the silver partitions it touches will grow.

**Questions**

1. Is our partitioning scheme and the fast/slow Spark job setup generally a good way to approach this problem?
2. What could be done to improve this setup? We would like to reduce the costs and the latency of the slow job and find a way so that it grows with the amount of data arriving at any day in bronze rather than with the size of the silver table

**Additional Infos**

- we need the MERGE command, as certain upstream services can re-process historic data, which should then update the silver table as well
- the schema  of the silver table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE silver.DeviceData (
  DeviceID LONG NOT NULL, -- the ID of the device that sent the data
  DataType STRING NOT NULL, -- the type of data it sent
  Timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, -- the timestamp of the data point
  Value DOUBLE NOT NULL, -- the value that the device sent
  UpdatedTimestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, -- the timestamp when the value arrived in bronze
  Partition_Date DATE NOT NULL, -- = TO_DATE(Timestamp)
  Partition_Hour INT NOT NULL -- = HOUR(Timestamp)
)
USING DELTA
PARTITIONED BY (Partition_Date, Partition_Hour)
LOCATION '...'
```

- our MERGE command:

```scala
val silverTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, silverDeltaLakeDirectory)

val batch = ... // the streaming update batch

// the dates and hours that we want to upsert, for partition pruning
// collected from the streaming update batch
val dates = "..."
val hours = "..."

val mergeCondition = s"""
  silver.Partition_Date IN ($dates)
  AND silver.Partition_Hour IN ($hours)
  AND silver.Partition_Date = batch.Partition_Date
  AND silver.Partition_Hour = batch.Partition_Hour
  AND silver.DeviceID = batch.DeviceID
  AND silver.Timestamp = batch.Timestamp
  AND silver.DataType = batch.DataType
"""

silverTable.alias("silver")
  .merge(batch.alias("batch"), mergeCondition)
  // only merge if the event is newer
  .whenMatched("batch.UpdatedTimestamp > silver.UpdatedTimestamp").updateAll
  .whenNotMatched.insertAll
  .execute
```

Comment: are you using Databricks, or it's your own delta lake?

Comment: @AlexOtt Its DataBricks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Databricks, there are several ways to optimize performance of the `merge into` operation:

- Perform Optimize with ZOrder on the columns that are part of the join condition.  This may depend on the specific DBR version, as older versions (prior to 7.6 IIRC) were using real ZOrder algorithm that is working well for smaller number of columns, while DBR 7.6+ uses by default Hilbert space-filling curves instead
- Use smaller file sizes - by default, `OPTIMIZE` creates files of 1Gb, that need to be rewritten.  You can use `spark.databricks.delta.optimize.maxFileSize` to set file size to 32Mb-64Mb range so it will rewrite less data
- Use conditions on partitions of the table (you're already doing that)
- Don't use auto-compaction because it can't do ZOrder, but instead run explicit optimize with ZOrder. See [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/auto-optimize.html#when-to-opt-out) on details
- Tune [indexing of the columns](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#data-skipping), so it will index only columns that are required for your condition and queries. It's partially related to the merging, but can slightly improve write speed because no statistics will be collected for columns that aren't used for queries.

This [presentation from Spark Summit](https://databricks.com/session_eu20/delta-lake-optimizing-merge) talks about optimization of the `merge into` - what metrics to watch, etc.

I'm not 100% sure that you need condition `silver.Partition_Date IN ($dates) AND silver.Partition_Hour IN ($hours)` because you may read more data than required if you don't have specific partitions in the incoming data, but it will require to look into the execution plan.  This [knowledge base article](https://kb.databricks.com/delta/delta-merge-into.html) explains how to make sure that `merge into` uses the partition pruning.

Update, December 2021st: In newer DBR versions (DBR 9+) there is a new functionality called [Low Shuffle Merge](https://databricks.com/blog/2021/09/08/announcing-public-preview-of-low-shuffle-merge.html) that prevents shuffling of not modified data, so the merge happens much faster. It could be enabled by setting `spark.databricks.delta.merge.enableLowShuffle` to `true`.

Comment: "Use smaller file sizes" - this I find very interesting, right now each (Date, Hour) partition contains one file with 300MB, which from my understanding means that ZORDER or the bloom filter indices don't do anything, as Spark will always read the complete file anyways. I will definitely give this a try. Having said that, do you think it even makes sense to have an Hour partition, if each partition is "only" 300MB?

Comment: your understanding is correct - if you have just one file per partition, then ZOrder & bloom filter & other optimizations won't help.  Regarding hour partition - it's really depends on how often batch data contains data for multiple hours of the day vs. only specific hours of day - in the latter case, partition per hour may help.

Comment: The batch updates will hit most of the hour partitions, so I guess it's not useful to have it

Comment: in this case, yes, maybe it won't be required, and combination of daily partitions with ZOrder, etc. may help better...